# VideoJS on iPad iOS5: concerning the width and height

Tags: ios5, video.js

I use videoJS to play a video on a HTML5 webpage. Everything is working well on PC (even with Safari), but on iPad (iOS 5), even if the video is playing well, I've got a problem with the size of the video – it is very small, and I don't know how to make it bigger.

I have tried adding `width` and `height` attributes and changing the default width and height in `video.js`.
Plus, my video is supposed to be 408px width and 520px height, and on iPad it's wider than high and there a black on each side.

How can I resolve this problem?

EDiT
@Emil thank you for your time. There is some codes :

How i include the video on my HTML page :

```
<video id='videoDavi' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' autoplay='autoplay' width='408' height='520' style='z-index: 1;' data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="#DOSSIER_SQUELETTE/video/bub_Intro.<?php echo $extension; ?>" type="<?php echo $type; ?>" /> 
</video>
```

The "$extension" and "$type" are meant to choose the right video for the right browser. I used to use the videoJS solution (`<video> <source [..]/> <source [...] /> <source [...] /> </video>`) but had to change in order to make i-dont-remember-what working.

I also included on my css :

```
video#videoDAVI_html5_api{ width: 408px; height: 520px; }
```

Because i saw throught a web inspector simulator that the code on the iPad was

```
<video id="videoDAVI_html5_api" autoplay src="video.mp4"></video>
```

(+ i forgot i'm also using easySlider 1.7)

Thanks

Comment: Please include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had it work on iPad.

I had this code under the `<video id="videoDavi"></video>`

```
<script>
     var homePlayer=_V_("videoDavi");
</script>
```

and had the video-js.css (it wasn't needed for the others, i still don't understand why iPad needs it)
Now it's not working at all on Android/Chrome, but working on Android/Firefox.. But I guess I'll find why, didn't have search yet.